# Printing lines which have a field number greater than, in AWK

Tags: bash, awk

I am writing a script in bash which takes a parameter and storing it;

```
threshold = $1
```

I then have sample data that looks something like:

```
5 blargh
6 tree
2 dog
1 fox
9 fridge
```

I wish to print only the lines which have their number greater than the number which is entered as the parameter (threshold).

I am currently using:

```
awk '{print $1 > $threshold}' ./file
```

But nothing prints out, help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You're close, but it needs to be more like this:

```
$ threshold=3
$ awk -v threshold="$threshold" '$1 > threshold' file
```

Creating a variable with `-v` avoids the ugliness of trying to expand shell variables within an `awk` script.

EDIT:

There are a few problems with the current code you've shown. The first is that your `awk` script is single quoted (good), which stops `$threshold` from expanding, and so the value is never inserted in your script. Second, your condition belongs outside the curly braces, which would make it:

```
$1 > threshold { print }
```

This works, but the `print is not necessary (it's the default action), which is why I shortened it to

```
$1 > threshold
```

Comment: Hmm, this still doesn't seem to work for me nothing seems to match and nothing gets printed, also does that way of setting threshold=3 make it equal to the parameter passed to the script?

Comment: @user2296424: 3 there was just as an example. If your script parameter is `$1`, you can use that instead.

Comment: It works, thanks! I'm still slightly confused though - how did that make it work, and why isn't it possible to do it the way I first thought?

Comment: You should use a space between `-v` and `variable name` to get better portability.  Older OSX has problem with missing space. You should also always double quote the variable.  Another way is to have variable after expression like: `awk '$1 > t' t="$threshold" file`